# Running an executable by calling it in a .sh file

Tags: bash, sh

I am very new to bash and using .sh files. I am trying to run the program aescrypt by calling it in a .sh file as follows (aescrypt is in the same directory as the .sh file) :

```
./aescrypt -e -p password file.txt
```

It throws the following error:

```
./aescrypt no such file or directory
```

Am I doing it wrong?

ps- I realy don't want to add it to the PATH variable as I will be using this on more than one computer that resets every day.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: maybe a shebang issue? Are you calling your .sh file with sudo? If so, could be this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144718/sudo-unable-to-execute-script-sh-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I ran it in sudo and still have the same problem.

Comment: It means there isn't an executable called `aescrypt` in your current directory.

Comment: BTW, naming bash scripts with `.sh` extensions is poor form. It falsely implies to readers that they can be run with a POSIX sh interpreter; means you need to rename the script to retain accuracy if you rewrite it in a different language; and is also unnecessary -- as long as your script starts with a shebang line, the OS (and any decent editor) will determine its file type from that. You don't run `ls.elf`, you just run `ls`; similarly, your script is `aescrypt`, not `aescrypt.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the script is irrelevant.  The thing that matters is the working directory of the process executing the script.  The simplest solution really is to add aescrypt to a standard location like `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.  If neither of those is acceptable, perhaps `/usr/local/bin` is an option.  Otherwise, just use the full path of `aescrypt` in your script.  Either hard code it, or if it is in the same directory as the script, try:

```
$(dirname $0)/aescrypt ...
```

(Note that hardcoding is more reliable, but less flexible.  If you move the executable, the script will break.  But using `dirname` will break if the script changes directory during execution.)

Comment: More reliable to use `$BASH_SOURCE` than `$0`; also makes the workaround (for the no-directory-name-present case) embedded in `dirname` unnecessary, allowing a more efficient parameter expansion to be used instead. Also, needs more quotes to handle directory names with spaces.

Comment: BASH_SOURCE is non-portable and will only work in bash.  A beginner in shell scripting would be well advised to avoid bash specific features.  Quoting is indeed necessary to handle terribly named directories, but placing a reasonably named executable in a poorly named directory is better solved by avoiding bad names!

Comment: Indeed -- I wouldn't have suggested BASH_SOURCE if the OP hadn't explicitly specified bash, but... well, such they've done. As for the naming -- do you suggest that the person writing a script can always control how and where that script is deployed? It's not always in your control; if someone has a home directory with a space (I've seen it happen), and wants to deploy your software inside it, why would you knowingly and intentionally include a bug that prevents that?

Comment: I think the world would be a better place if all software that tried to put executables in directories with whitespace in the name would fail!  Is it worth the effort to "fix" unix so that directories containing `:` can be in PATH?    If someone chooses to put a script in a directory with whitespace in the name, the failure of that script is a good thing.  The correct solution is to hard code the path, or put the executable in a standard location.  Anything else is a hack.

Answer (score -1):

how about if you call the program like ./aescrypt.sh, thats the way to call an .sh programm througt the terminal

First off all, you have also to change the permissions of the file to make it executable, the way to make that is to write in the terminal, the command:

sudo chmod 765 aescrypt.sh

For that you have to be located where the file is